# Crashplan and Systemd

Tags: 16.04, systemd, crashplan

I installed Crashplan on my headless 16.04 server, but I'm having trouble with Systemd. As per the instructions [here](https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Troubleshooting/CrashPlan_App_Does_Not_Restart_After_Linux_Reboots_Or_Upgrades#Installing_The_Systemd_Script), I installed the systemd script. The only problem is, `/opt/proserver/` does not exist. I'm not really sure what I do need to run to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

If you've installed Crashplan and their documentation refers to the location of `/opt/proserver` as where Crashplan should already be installed, then Crashplan's documentation is not accurate and should contact them for support.

You could run:

```
ls /opt
```

To see if Crashplan was installed in another directory below `/opt`. If you find it, you could adjust the paths in the `systemd` files accordingly.